# Bash script has different behavior when launched from PHP shell_exec

Tags: php, bash

script.sh

```
cd ~/scripts
acname=$(cat acname.txt)
days=$(cat days.txt)
nbmessages=`ls -l message_*.txt | wc -l`
today=`date +%Y%m%d`
#
echo $acname >> ./log.txt
echo $days >> ./log.txt
echo $nbmessages >> ./log.txt
echo $today >> ./log.txt
```

if I run script.sh in a shell prompt, log.txt shows:

```
alex8
4
5
20140124
```

which is correct

If I run script.sh using shell_exec function in PHP, log.txt shows:

```
log.txt: 


0
20140124
```

Therefore getting the content of a file doesn't work, nor counting the files with a specific pattern (got 0 when it should be 5), while the date command still works.
Any idea ?
Many thanks in advance !

Comment: `~/scripts` goes to the scripts subdir of YOUR home dir. This may be a different place than the home dir of the web server process running php.

Comment: I'll try to echo pwd and see where I am in each case

Comment: and you were correct, pwd give a different dir in the 2 cases

Comment: No problem; upgraded to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/scripts` goes to the scripts subdir of YOUR home dir. This may be a different place than the home dir of the web server process running php.

In general using full paths can help alleviate issues like this, but you will still have to contend with ensuring the web server process has the rights to the files in question.